# Why there isn't a protocol in Google Developer Library's jQuery link?

Tags: jquery

I am always in doubt. I consider that google is intelligent .
 But when i copy the jquery link for there developer site
   https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide the following jquery link

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sample Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('hello');
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

it does not work for me

But when i change it with

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('hello');
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

it works for me

Why has google not appended `http:` in the link? is it deliberate?

I am using mozilla as browser

Comment: You have a typo on the first line with `://`

Comment: no it's not that while positing the question by mistake i have that

Comment: Because you are opening (*most likely*) the file from you disk, and not viewing it through a server. So your protocol is `file://` which cannot does not work with this code..

Comment: No worries - see my answer below - it's the protocol causing you problems.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli My point exactly :)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes you are correct i copied the file on the server and it worked there . Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google chose to leave out the protocol so that its snippet can work across both `http` and `https` pages by inheriting the current protocol.

---

**EDIT**

If you are opening the html file with your browser, the default protocol is `file://` so that's why it won't work. You will have to host the file inside a web server to make it work with the `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` url.

Comment: it's not that i have by mistaken posted them in the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just reading the comment and editing my answer; it wasn't my intention to copy your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this, aside from the minor typo, is that protocol - less urls will not work locally with out a server.  The second version, you should never put code/markup outside `html`.

Use the following:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hello');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need http or https on your server, just drop the protocol.